# Fetch values from 2 fields and show multiplication in third field

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

I have a form which includes product name dropdown, quantity field & amount field. I want to fetch price from database when product name is selected and when quantity entered want to show multiplication of price of selected product and quantity in Total amount field. I want to use Jquery.

image of form:
[image: form]

This is my code:

```
<div class="section row mb10" style="">
  <label for="ordered-product" class="field-label col-md-2 text-center"><i class="fa fa-product"></i></label>
  <div class="col-md-3">
     <label class="field select">
            <select name="orderedproduct[]" id="orderedproduct">
              <option>Select Ordered Product</option>
                <?php
                $query="SELECT * FROM product_list";
                $res=mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
                while($row=mysql_fetch_array($res)){
                echo "<option value='". $row['product_id'] ."'>" .$row['product_name'] ."</option>" ;
                      }
                ?>
            </select>       
      </label>
  </div>
  <label for="product-qty" class="field-label col-md-1 text-center"><i class="fa fa-cubes"></i></label>
  <div class="col-md-2">
    <label for="product-qty" class="field prepend-icon">
    <input type="text" name="productqty[]" id="productqty" class="gui-input" placeholder="Quantity">
    </label>
  </div>
  <label for="order-amount" class="field-label col-md-1 text-center"><i class="fa fa-inr"></i></label>
  <div class="col-md-2">
    <label for="order-ammount" class="field prepend-icon">
      <input type="text" name="orderammount[]" id="orderammount" class="gui-input" disable placeholder="Total Amount">
    </label>
   </div>
</div>
```

Any help will be appreciated. Thank you.

Jquery:

```
$('#orderedproduct','#productqty').change(function(){
    var oproductname = $(this).val();
    $.ajax(
            type:'POST';
            data:{oproductname:oproductname},
            url:'ajax pages/amount.php',
            success:function(data){
                $('#orderedamount').val(data);
    }
});
});
```

Comment: we do help , when you provide the code that is not working, not when you expect us to code it for you

Comment: you can do it in javascript or jquery. try some code first, and ask help if your code is not working

Comment: @geeth i have done this jquery but i am new to this so i dont't know that much.

Comment: @geeth when i do this other jquery is disabled.

Comment: checkout my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need to use ajax to perform this multiplication only. If you are using it for another reason, you can continue like that. Otherwise the following code will work.

You are not listed price for product anywhere. So change your select option like as follows :

```
echo '<option value='". $row['product_id'] ."' data-price="'.$row['product_price'].'">' .$row['product_name'] .'</option>' ;


$(document).on('change, focusout', '#orderedproduct,#productqty', function(){
    var oproductname = $(this).val();
    var productQty = parseInt($('#productqty').val());
    var productPrice = parseFloat($('#orderedproduct').find(':selected').data('price'));
    var totalAmount = productQty * productPrice ;
    if(!isNaN(totalAmount)) { 
        $('#orderedamount').val(totalAmount );
    }

});
```

Comment: i want to fetch selected product's price when product is selected. how can i include external php, sql code  file to fetch selected product price ?

Comment: when you fetch product details, it may contain its price. I edited my code. just check it out

Comment: bro, it is not getting total amount. check fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/iamtriples/4hdm433h/

Comment: looks like your jquery event not triggering. did you load the jquery file

Comment: one last thing i am adding same multiple rows using button. so it is not working for 2nd, 3rd rows

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158042/discussion-between-geeth-and-shubham-shah).

Answer (score 0):

i dont know but i hope this should be helpful

```js
$('#qty').keyup(function () {
  var price = $('.price').val();
    var qty = $('#qty').val();
   
    var total = price * qty;
    $('#total').val(total);
     
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="price" placeholder="Product Price">
<input type="text" id="qty" placeholder="Product Quantity">
<br><br>
<input type="text" id="total" placeholder="Total">
```